# python import module installed

Tags: python, c++, import, module

I installed a library "essentia" on my linux machine but I don't know how to use it in my python or c++ project.
When I do import essentia I get a "import essentia could not be resolved". It must be something trivial in python programming but I just can't figure out how to use libraries.
Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up libraries is the easiest for linux on python. Open up  terminal and type :

```
pip install essentia
```

then in python do:

```
import essentia
```

Comment: I installed it just like written here : https://essentia.upf.edu/installing.html with ./waf install but in visual code the import says "not resolved" . Am I missing something ?

Comment: if you were using waf you were building it from source, is that what you were attempting? If you just want to use the library you don't have to compile it yourself, you can just do pip install.